# Validating a proof that powers of 2 cannot be a sum of consecutive positive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, summation

I purchased a book for math puzzles. It contained a puzzle summed up as some person is reading a book. They are asked to sum the pages they just read. It's either $412$ or $512$. Which is it?

I brute forced my way to an answer with excel because I didn't know that the summation of consecutive integers could not be a power of two. Found the values to be 8 consecutive integers starting with $48$. $(48 + ... + 55 = 412)$. Anyway... I also brute forced my way to the fact that

$$\sum_{i=0}^n i = \frac {n(n + 1)}{2}$$

The proof in the back states that if you start at $m + 1$ and end at $n$ ($\sum_{i=m+1}^n i$) that the solution would be

$$\frac {n(n+1)}{2} - \frac{m(m+1)}{2}$$

This just doesn't feel right to me at all. I suppose it might depend on how you look at it, but if you assumed m to be the starting position, $48$ in this case, I would start as $m + 1$ and be m less than the sum $(364)$.

I had other issues that I figured out while typing this out, but I got those worked out, but I cannot for the life of me determine why $m + 1$ is used. It's not like this is coding and it's an array position being used as something else. I suppose this might be one of the nuances of proofs that will take some time to learn, or it could be completely random and wrong... I don't know. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: With $n=55$ and $m=47$, you have $(m+1)+(m+2)+\cdots +n= 48+49+\cdots+55=\frac {55 \times 56 }{2} - \frac{47 \times 48}{2} = 412$

Comment: might want to look up triangular numbers as that what any sum of consecutive numbers is the difference of and that's basically what the solution says. it just specifies which triangular numbers to subtract.

Comment: 412 is a [polite number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polite_number) while 512 is not (as it is a power of $2$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of the numbers

$$
0,1,\dots,m,m+1,\dots, n
$$

is

$$
\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$

The sum of the numbers

$$
0,1,\dots,m
$$

is

$$
\frac{m(m+1)}{2}
$$

Therefore, the sum of the numbers
$$
m+1,\dots,n
$$
is
$$
\frac{n(n+1)}{2} - \frac{m(m+1)}{2}
$$

Comment: Well put! I suppose it would just be a matter of personal preference as to whether you used m and m+1 or m-1 and m. Unless it's one of those weird unspoken/unwritten standardized things. Either way, thanks!

Comment: @abyssmu I don't think it's standardized.  But if you use $m$ and $m-1$ then you have to change the expression to $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} - \frac{(m-1)m}{2}$, which is arguably less neat.

Answer (score 2):

If it's possible then
$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-\frac{m(m+1)}{2}=2^{k-1}$$ or
$$(n-m)(n+m+1)=2^k,$$ where $k$ is a natural number and since $n-m+n+m+1$ is odd,
we obtain $n-m=1$,

$m=2^{k-1}-1$, which says that we have no more that one number in our sum.